# Como configurar o Netbeans para trabalhar com o PHPUnit em ambiente virtualizado?

Tags: php, netbeans, testes-de-unidade, phpunit

Utilizo no Mac o Netbeans 7.4 para programar. E para não ter que instalar o PHP e PHPUnit, gostaria de executar o PHPUnit instalado em uma máquina virtual que possui todo um ambiente de integração já configurado. Está prática vem sendo muito utilizada, e indicada em sites como o [PHP The Right Way](http://br.phptherightway.com/#servidores_virtuais_ou_dedicados).

Para usar o PHPUnit integrado com o Netbeans, é preciso indicar um arquivo que será usado para executar os comandos do PHPUnit, podendo ser o próprio executável do PHPUnit ou um script. Para indicar o arquivo, é necessário que esteja na mesma maquina onde está instalado o Netbeans para que ele consiga acessá-lo.

**Sendo assim, como configuro o Netbeans para executar o PHPUnit que está instalado na maquina virtual?**

Pesquisando, encontrei alguns tutoriais que mostram scripts que executam o PHPUnit na maquina virtual usando SSH ou a ferramenta de controle de maquinas virtuais do Virtual Box.

[Este](http://question.askprogramming.com/1072886/netbeans-virtual-box-guest-installation-phpunit.html) aparentemente funcionaria, porem é para Windows e necessita de um caminho específico de uma pasta de testes. Eu possuo vários projetos no Netbeans, se eu fixar uma pasta de testes neste script, conseguiria usar o PHPUnit para apenas um projeto.

Outro problema que tenho ao criar um script para o Netbeans executar o PHPUnit é que os caminhos locais são diferentes do servidor virtualizado. Achei outras soluções usando SSH, porém a conexão via SSH requer senha, o que dificulta usar o comando SSH.

**O ambiente de desenvolvimento**

- MacBook com o Mavericks OS X 10.9.1
- Servidor virtualizado no Virtual Box 4.3.6 com o Ubuntu Server 12 usando Bridge Adapter
- Apache, PHP e MySQL, XDebug, PHPUnit e outras ferramentas de integração contínua instalados no servidor virtualizado
- A Pasta "~/Sites" está compartilhada com a maquina virtual e montada em "/var/www". Sendo assim o que eu altero na pasta "~/Sites" e as alterações ficam disponíveis para a maquina virtual executar.

Comment: Olá. Você poderia explicar melhor o seu problema? O que não funciona no tutorial?

Comment: O tutorial é para windows, e o arquivo bat possui a configuração fixa do projeto, indicando o arquivo de bootstrap e caminho de tests. Isso impede que eu teste mais de um projeto aberto no meu netbeans usando o mesmo script.

Comment: Primeiramente você precisa em seu post dizer qual é o problema, pois você apenas diz que está a tentar configurar o ambiente para rodar PHPUnit utilizando Netbeans (não informou versão), e uma maquina virtual que faz o trabalho do PHP.
Talvez seja mais interessante utilizar o servidor apache+php que já vem com o OSX, eu mesmo faço isto não é difícil. Tudo se encontra em /private/etc/apache2 e em /private/etc se encontra um arquivo php.ini.default basta fazer uma copia pro mesmo local sem o .default que você pode utilizar para configurações do php.ini.

Comment: A utilização da maquina virtual, tem várias vantagens como pode ler sobre neste link http://eltonminetto.net/blog/2012/04/02/usando-o-vagrant-para-criar-maquinas-virtuais-para-desenvolvimento-e-testes/

Alem de permitir que eu trabalhe em equipe usando sempre a mesma configuração, posso aproximar bastante do ambiente de produção, alem de não precisar reinstalar e configurar tudo sempre que precisar mudar de computador, basta rodar a maquina virtual.

Comment: É exatamente o que descrivi. Em pesquisas no google se pesquisar "netbeans virtualbox xdebug" vai encontrar muita coisa, ou mesmo procurando por vagrant.

O que eu não quero é ter que instalar na minha maquina o php só para rodar o phpunit. Na maquina virtual já tem um servidor de integração continua todo configurado.

Comment: A quem interessar, esta pergunta está em discussão no meta: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/719/o-que-fazer-quando-uma-pergunta-e-posta-em-suspensao-por-usuarios-que-nao-possue.

Comment: Se você tiver a chave pública da sua máquina no servidor virtual, dá para usar SSH sem precisar digitar a senha, ver http://www.vivaolinux.com.br/dica/SSH-sem-senha

Answer (score 3):

É preciso configurar bem o arquivo `phpunit-remote.sh` e o rede/network da máquina virtual.

A rede da máquina virtual está em NAT ou Bridge Adapter?

Recomendo usar *Bridged Adapter* para a maquina ter um *ip* próprio dentro da rede.

Depois é saber qual é o ip da maquina na rede com `ifconfig`

E configurar no arquivo `.sh`

```
REMOTE_SERVER=vmuser@ip.do.vm
```

mais nao sei.

Comment: está em bridge, mas ssh nao dá pra passar a senha de conexão direto via linha de comando. ou tem?